# Find libraries a binary was linked against

Tags: linux, macos, shared-libraries

I know that there is a command that lists me the libs and respective versions a software
was linked against.

Something with ld or libtool?

But I just cannot remember. Spent some time on google but didn't come up with anything useful.

**Update**
`ldd <binary>` would help on linux, ([from](https://superuser.com/a/239593/2650) @[Ernelli](https://superuser.com/users/35754/ernelli)) while I found that `otool -L <binary>` does something similar on MacOS X.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50159/show-all-libraries-used-by-executables-on-linux

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Try 
   ldd *binary-exec*

Example:

```
~$ ldd /bin/bash
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00606000)
    libncurses.so.5 => /lib/libncurses.so.5 (0x00943000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2 (0x00c5d000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0x003e9000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00a41000)
```

Comment: Dang! So my first try was right. Just need to install it on my Mac so it acutally knows the command ;-)

Comment: @er4z0r: FYI, Mac OS is BSD, _not Linux_.

Comment: grwaity: you are right. While ldd would help on linux I found that  'otool -L <binary>' does something similar.

Answer (score 20):

To find what it directly needs:

```
readelf -d APP | grep NEEDED
```

`ldd` as mentioned elsewhere will show all direct and indirect libs - everything it needs at runtime.  This may not be a complete list, since you may dynamically open things with dlopen(), but this should work 99% of the time.

ld and libtool are used at compile/link time.  They aren't useful once you have an app.

**EDIT** I can see by later answers you were asking about OSX, but I want to add to my answer on Linux tools:

One thing I forgot to mention, quite a while ago; you asked about versions. Neither `ldd` nor `readelf` will answer the "what version" question. They will tell you the filename of the library you are looking for, and the naming convention may have some version info, but nothing enforces this. Symbols may be versioned, and you would have to much about even lower level with `nm` to see these,

Answer (score 11):

Another way would be to use objdump.

> objdump -x "binary" | grep NEEDED

This shows all needed dependencies only for this binary. Very useful.

Answer (score 0):

The **other answers** miss an important point:

Shared libs can either be **directly** linked, or **indirectly** linked through another lib.

For only the **directly linked**:

> objdump --private-headers "${bin}" | grep 'NEEDED' | cut --delimiter=' '
> --fields=18-

For **all**:

> ldd "${bin}" | cut --fields=2 | cut --delimiter=' ' --fields=1 | rev | cut --delimiter='/' --fields=1 | rev | sort --unique --version-sort